# Delete/remove the closest element with a class

Tags: jquery

I am trying to delete/remove the closest ".step" on ".delete" button click. So as it delete the .step above the .delete button.

```
 <div class="step"></div>
 <div class="new"></div>
 <div class="delete"></div>

<div class="step"></div>
 <div class="new"></div>
 <div class="delete"></div>

<div class="step"></div>
 <div class="new"></div>
 <div class="delete"></div>
```

Here is my jQuery:

```
   $('.delete').click(function(){
       $(this).find('div.step').remove();    
     });
```

How should I grub this step? Thank you for your help!

Comment: You can use closest() http://api.jquery.com/closest/

Comment: @SrikanthAD no, it is not a parent of .delete

Comment: and here comes problems once a div.step has been removed and same button click again... Wrap each of your 'blocks' inside their own container

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have **multiple** ID's that is invalid html. Maybe its just a example, otherwise fix that.

To delete the div you can remove and double check it has the right class like this:

```
$('.delete').click(function () {
    var $wanted = $(this).prev().prev();
    if ($wanted.hasClass('step')) $wanted.remove();
});
```

### Demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/b5NCL/)

Comment: You really should cache that `$(this).prev().prev()` object (rather than traverse to it twice, once to assess and once to remove). Also: what `id`s? I honestly can't see any (unless they were removed in a grace-period edit or something?).

Answer (score 6):

I'd suggest, given that HTML:

```
$('.delete').click(function(){
    $(this).prevAll('.step').first().remove();    
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/4HgKb/).

Adapted the above (to prevent problems on the second click of the `.delete` element):

```
$('.delete').click(function(){
    $(this).prevUntil('.delete').first().prev('.step').remove();
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/4HgKb/2/).

Though it'd be much easier if the `.step` was an ancestor, or wrapped in a parent element:

```
<div>
    <div class="step"></div>
    <div class="new" id="addNextSlide"></div>
    <div class="delete"></div>
</div>
```

Which would enable the following:

```
$('.delete').click(function(){
    $(this).parent().find('.step').remove();    
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/4HgKb/1/).

References:

- [`click()`](http://api.jquery.com/click/).
- [`find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/).
- [`first()`](http://api.jquery.com/first/).
- [`parent()`](http://api.jquery.com/parent/).
- [`prevAll()`](http://api.jquery.com/prevAll/).
- [`prevUntil()`](http://api.jquery.com/prevUntil/).
- [`remove()`](http://api.jquery.com/femove/).

Comment: Most accurate answer.

Answer (score 2):

select the previous `.new`, then the previous `.step`, and remove it:

```
$('.delete').on('click', function(){
   $(this).prev('.new').prev('.step').remove();    
});
```

Answer (score 0):

[Use `prev`](http://api.jquery.com/prev/).

```
$('.delete-slide').click(function(){
    $(this).prev('div.step').remove();    
});
```